# No hover event after I used .empty() and .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-hover

I have a sortable list (jQuery UI) that I want to sort programmatically using the ids of the 
"li" elements. (they are all numbers).

To do that, I have made this function:

```
function resetList()
{
   var orderedItems = new Array();
   var unorderedItems = $("#sortable").find('li');

   for(var i = 0; i < unorderdItems.length; i++)
   {
       var counter = 0;
       var check = false;
       do {

           if(unorderedItems[counter].id == (i+1))
           {
                check = true;
                orderedItems.push(unorderedItems[counter]);                   
           }
           counter++;  

       } while (!check && counter < unorderedItems.length);
    } 

    $("#sortable").empty().html(orderedItems);           
}
```

I think that works quite well (i am new to javascript, so i don't know if that code is "professional")

The problem is that after I've called the function no jQuery hover or mouseover events are firing anymore (have been working before)

The content of my "li" elements:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="image" style=\"height:100%; width:100%;">
        <img class="overlay" src="img/pic.png" height="200" width="200" style="height:200px; width:200px; visibility:hidden;" />
    </div>;
</li>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e)
{
//make overlay visible  
}, function(e) 
{       
//hide overlay      
});
```

Any ideas why the hover function does not work after I called resetList()?

Sorry about the bad english and thank you for any help!

-Nick

Comment: When you set hover in JavaScript you hook it to the element that exists on that moment. Options: Set the hover again. Check out jquery.live or do it with css.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you are removing the element that has `hover` functionality applied to it and are recreating it.  I'm guessing that since you are destroying all those elements with your `.empty()` you will have to re-apply whatever code you are using to apply the hover functionality in the first place.

Comment: @ReneGeuze The `.live()` jQuery function has been deprecated for quite some time now. `.on()` for jQuery 1.7+, otherwise `.delegate()`.

Comment: I didn't mean the actual live() function. For some reason I rather call it live with whatever function name it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery 1.7 or higher use .on else use .delegate

```
$(".image").on("mouseover mouseout",function(evt){
    if (evt.type == 'mouseover') {
           // do something on mouseover
        alert("over");
      } else {
        // do something on mouseout
        alert("out");
      }
     });
```

earlier version of jquery

```
$("body").delegate(".image","hover",function(evt){
    if (evt.type == 'mouseenter') {
        // do something on mouseover
        alert("over");
    }else {
        // do something on mouseout
        alert("out");
        }
});
```

you are right,changed to delegate

Dafen, hover wont work elements that are dynamically created from javascript, hence using .on or delegate, anyways you have found your answer, just correcting my answer so that no one does same mistake i have done.

Comment: Earlier versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`, not `.live()` - unless you're so far behind that you don't have `.delegate()` either (in which case you **really** need to update). The `.live()` function has been deprecated for *months*, and the documentation clearly states (in multiple places) that `.delegate()` is the preferred function for versions of jQuery prior to 1.7.

Comment: Is $(".image").on("hover",function() {}); better than .hover()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that after you sort your elements, new dom elements get added to your page, replacing the old ones.  As a result your event handlers get lost.  You should be able to fix it quite easily by using delegated events with `on`

```
$(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", ".image", function() { .....

$(".ui-state-default").on("mouseleave", ".image", function() { .....
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Dafen.  If any answer here helped you feel free to click the check mark beside it to indicate that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be difficult, integers aren't valid HTML IDs (IDs should start with a letter [A-Za-z])